# javascript with google maps : markers are not displayed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, netbeans

I successfully managed to get markers displayed in a google map, but due to code improvement reasons, I grouped the declarations of companies (which are represented by markers) in one part of the code, the displaying par is thus reduced to a for loop.

but only the map is displayed, not the markers.why?

here is the code:(only the last company infos are displayed; after creation they are stored in the "entreprises" field, which is an array.

```
var anx_wing_addresse = '<div style="width:240px;margin:0 0 20px
20px;height:130px;text-align:left;color:black"><h1>Gerwing-Sehn GmbH & Co. KG</h1>' +
                    '<p>Oststra&beta;e 65<br/>' +
                    'D-66386 St Ingbert<br/>' +
                    'www.sehn.de</p>' +
                    '<p>T�l : +49(0)6894 3873-160<br/>' +
                    'Fax : +49(0)6894 3873-169</p></div>';
            var anx_wing = new Entreprise("Gerwing-Sehn GmbH & Co. KG", anx_wing_addresse,
                    "anx_gerwing", false, false, false, true,
                    49.274763, 7.129415,
                    'images/icones_google_maps/noir20.png');
            entreprises.push(anx_wing);

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.365613, 7.556992);
            //objet contenant des propri�t�s avec des identificateurs pr�d�finis dans Google Maps permettant
            //de d�finir des options d'affichage de notre carte
            var options = {
                center: latlng,
                zoom: 6,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                draggable: true
            };

            //constructeur de la carte qui prend en param�tre le conteneur HTML
            //dans lequel la carte doit s'afficher et les options
            var carte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("carte"), options);

            for (ent in entreprises) {



                infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: ent.descriptionHTML
                });

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: ent.loc,
                    map: carte,
                    title: ent.nom,
                    icon: ent.chemin_image
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: ent.descriptionHTML
                    }).open(marker);
                });

            }
```

is the for...in loop wrong?

thank you for your attention

olivier

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your markers to collection:

```
var markers = [];
var counter = 0;
for (ent in entreprises) {
    infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: ent.descriptionHTML
    });

    markers[counter] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: ent.loc,
        map: carte,
        title: ent.nom,
        icon: ent.chemin_image
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[counter], 'click', function() {
        new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: ent.descriptionHTML
        }).open(markers[counter]);
    });
    counter++;
}
```

Also your `ent.loc` must be valid `google.maps.LatLng` object

Comment: thanks, but the markers are still not displayed. could it be the path to the image the error, I mean : the path is relative to the html file, not to the js file(the js file is in the "js" directory, and the images in an "images" repository.I could test it myself but I'd rather ask you because there are 8 companies, so it makes 8 changes in different parts of the code, eventuelly for nothing...And for the markers answer, is it due to reassignements to the same variable?What is the rules concerning this in javascript?

Comment: ``images`` path must be related to root folder, where located your site or application. So, if you have this structure: ``www --images --js index.html`` your icon should like this ``icon: /images/some_icon.png``. For testing you can remove icon property and in this case you should to see default google markers

Comment: the test without the icon declaration is a failure, the problem is away.I had 2 warnings in netbeans : 1/"the global variable "ent" is not defined.I solved this with "for (var ent in entreprises)..." 2/"the global variable "google" is not declared", in the line of the instanciation if the marker...is it because the javascript function is in a proper js file, not in the HTML file(where there is a javascript import of the google API)

Comment: Hurrah!it works, with "entreprises.forEach(function(ent){ ... });.the problem came from the loop.thanks anyway.